# RAZOR PAGES .NET CORE 2.0, Populating a dropdown based on the selection in another dropdown

Tags: razor, drop-down-menu, .net-core

I am working on an application in .Net Core 2.0 Razor Pages using Entity Framework (Not MVC), 
i.e. There are models and Razor Page using one of those models. Every Razor page has a .cshtml page(view page which can also have c# code within razor syntax),
and a .cshtml.cs file which is the code-behind consisting of C# code with Get and Post methods.

I have tried all possible research on the internet including the following links which use JS or JQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/k148pk76/1/
Countrylawstable is the model I am using. I tried using Javascript which is getting me the frontend but the values aren't reflecting on the database.
The GetCommonCodes is a class which helps get the list of countries from the database. I want the country and state names to be populated from the database.
Someone please help, I have tried many solutions on the internet but all of them use the MVC.
Below is my code:

```
..
... 
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Country</label>   
<select asp-for="Countrylawstable.Country" class="form-control">
<option value="N/A"> Please Select Country</option>
@foreach (var item in DocumintAdmin.Models.GetCommonCodes.Commoncodeslist)
    {
        if (item.Refcodetype.Equals("COUNTRY"))
        {
            <option value="@item.Refcode"> @item.Refdesc</option>
        }
    }
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="Countrylawstable.Country" class="text-danger"> 
</span>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">State</label>
<select asp-for="Countrylawstable.Countrystate" class="form-control" >
<option value=""disabled selected>Select State</option>

</select>
<span asp-validation-for="Countrylawstable.Countrystate"></span>
</div>
```